# Lucene.NET + Azure + AzureDirectory or something else?

Tags: full-text-search, azure, lucene.net, azure-sql-database

Good morning.

I am currently working on a project which was originally going to be hosted on a physical server with SQL2k8R2, but it looks like we are moving towards the cloud and Azure... Since SQL Azure does not currently support Full Text Indexing, i have been looking at Lucene.NET with the [AzureDirectory project](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/AzureDirectory) for back end storage. The way this will work is that updates will come in and be queued. once processed, they will be placed in a ToIndex queue, which will kick off Lucene.NET indexing. I am just wondering if there would be a better way of doing this? We dont **need** to use Azure for this project, so if there is a better solution somewhere, please tell us... main requirement for hosting is it is in Europe...(Azure and Amazon Data centers in Dublin is handy, RackSpace in US is not so handy).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used that project, but it looks promising. From what I understand, the basic issue is that Lucene requires a file-system. I see 2 other possible solutions (basically just doing what the library does):

1. Use Azure Drive Storage and a worker role
2. Use Drive storage, but use a VM (if there are config issues with using a worker role)

http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9710117

SQLite also has full text search available, but it has the same basic issue - it requires a filesystem:
http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html

Comment: thanks for the answers. for number 1, this has a problem since there could be multiple instances each talking to the storage. this is the current problem i am having with AzureDirectory... AzureDirectory locks the blob when it checks it out, but for some unknown reason, multiple instances can lock it at the same time... drive storage is limited to single instances talking to the storage. As for SQLLite, i will look into this. thing is, there is a LOT of storage... and your back to blob storage and locking...

Comment: Unfortunately the only way I see around that is to duplicate the indexes for each instance. Have a single Instance create the indexes and store them in blobs. On instance startup, each instance can copy and mount those blobs.

Comment: after looking into this a bit more, i have found that Azure Drives are not linked to a single machine only. only one machine can have them mounted, but they can be snapshotted and used by other machines. this is how we used it in the end. I have one Indexer running, using the VHD drive. every couple of min, it creates a snapshot and writes the address to Blob Storage. 2 worker roles then take that URL and mount the snapshot for Querying on the DB. So far, so good... Not ideal, but working for us...

Answer (score 0):

I have another solution for you, but it's a bit more radical, and a bit more of a conceptual one.

You could create your own indexes, using azure table storage. Create partitions based on each word in your documents, as all tables are indexed on the partitionkey, per word search should be fast, and just do memory joins for multiple word searches.

Comment: sounds like an option, but now we are at the "reinventing the wheel" part... plus lucene.net has some nice features for stemming, etc...

Comment: Perhaps you could crack open the Lucene.Net source and write a table store provider for it. I know they're desperately looking for contributors.

Comment: Starting to look at the drive storage system for azure. This, if I am reading the documentation correctly, which I like to think i am, should keep the VHD active, even if the main machine goes down. This way, I can store the index on once VHD, make sure that only one machine can use that, and have a arrive on this allowing other instances to run search. Some testing of this is required, but if it works, it should make life easier! And a lucene provider for this should be quite simple... Might not even be needed... Directory stooge could work with it...

Answer (score 0):

You could host it as an Azure Website as long as your Lucene index is less than 1GB.

I did this recently when I rewrote [Ask Jon Skeet](http://askjonskeet.com/) to be hosted as a self contained Azure Website. It uses WebBackgrounder to poll the Stackoverflow API for changes, before updating the Lucene index.